# How can I suppress "Sent $X packet" output in Scapy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy

I have a script that is sending out `802.11` beacon frames at the typical beacon interval of 102 seconds. However, each time a beacon frame is sent, it prints `Sent 1 packet.` With an interval of 102ms, this obviously spams a lot of `Sent 1 packet` messages and prevents me from providing useful output of what my script is doing. Is there a way to suppress these messages?

I previously found

[surpress scapy warning message when importing the module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249341/surpress-scapy-warning-message-when-importing-the-module)

But it only removes the `no route` warning in scapy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any of the `send` methods add the following option to the function call -

```
verbose=False
```

Change your call to look like -

```
send(IP(), verbose=False)
```

You can also change the `conf.verb` to `0` to suppress verbose messages in functions.